# How long does it take to fast sync a geth node in 2021?

Tags: go-ethereum, fast-sync

I am trying to fast sync a geth node with the mainnet. On a server with equipped a mechanical hard disk, an old-ish 24-core Xeon processor, and 96 GB RAM, it sync 4 block per minutes on average. I don't see any way the sync will ever finish. Is it normal? What is the typical fast sync speed expected with geth (1.10.3-stable)? How long does it take a get node to come to sync with the mainnet in 2021? Pretty much all the information available on Google are out of date.

Answer (score 2):

can't use an HDD, need to use an SSD.

"Q: Wait, so I can’t run a full node on an HDD?

A: Unfortunately not. Doing a fast sync on an HDD will take more time than you’re willing to wait with the current data schema. Even if you do wait it out, an HDD will not be able to keep up with the read/write requirements of transaction processing on mainnet.

You however should be able to run a light client on an HDD with minimal impact on system resources. If you wish to run a full node however, an SSD is your only option."

https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/faq

Comment: [Here is my guide on how to configure high-speed SSD NVMe RAID0 on your Linux server to run geth nodes](https://tradingstrategy.ai/blog/announcing-the-trading-data-availability-for-binance-smart-chain).