# Start and HTTP JSON-RPC geth on android?

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging, golang, java, android

Is it possible to change the code in /mobile to allow for a json-rpc api to be spawned on an android?
Or is there something I need to do in Java with the NodeConfig?

I already managed to run a light-node on mobile.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Running an Ethereum node requires a high-performance server with SSD disk](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/102473/620). You cannot run Ethereum node, or any other meaningful blockchain node, on mobile.

Comment: I already managed to run a light-node on mobile; I just need to also open a http-rpc gateway with it

Comment: Node that light node cannot serve all JSON-RPC endpoints.

Comment: You sure? I managed to get it working on my desktop, also a light node.

Comment: Yes, because light node does not have the data. It depends on what you are building.